# Spy on global fetch (which URL is hit)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch, react-testing-library

I have this function to spy on global fetch and return a value

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockResolvedValue({json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(user)})
```

I want to find out what API route is hit when this is called. For example I want to do:

```
console.log(spy.showFetchURL)
```

and have it return `'http//:localhost/**user**'` for debugging purposes

Comment: `spyOn` creates a mock function, whose [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) provides information about how to interact with it.

Comment: Alternatively you can use something like https://mswjs.io/ instead of mocking the fetch API (which you don't own).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.mockImplementation()` like this for example:

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation((url) => {
  switch (url) {
    case 'https://example-1.com?param1=true&param2=false':
      return Promise.resolve({
        status: 200,
        json: () => Promise.resolve({
          // mocked data object/array here
        })
      })
    break

    case 'https://example-2.com?param1=false&param2=true&param3=something':
      return Promise.resolve({
        status: 200,
        json: () => Promise.resolve({
          // mocked data object/array here
        })
      })
    break

    // ...etc
  }
})
```